# .NET 6 - EF : how do I insert one to many relation ship with null reference?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a one-to-many relationship with `Author` and `Books`. What I want to do is insert authors, but I don't know what books they released yet, so the books are empty for now.

I've tried different logic and relationship connection between author and books but still get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code:

```
public class Author
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book>? Book { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
}

public class Books
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Author? Author{ get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship connection between Author and Books

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Book)
            .WithOne(a => a.Author)
            .HasForeignKey(aa => aa.AuthorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Attempt at inserting data into `Author` with no books yet:

```
_context.Author.Add(request.Author);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration :

> Whether starting with the Company or Employee entity, this configuration will result in an optional relationship. A foreign key shadow property named CompanyId will be introduced by EF Core to the Employee entity which will be nullable.

Btw you don't need following specify nullable for `string` and `Book` - they are nullable by default. `Book` is class which is reference type and `string` is "special" reference type which has some behaviour of value type.

UPDATE COMPLETE WORKING EXAMPLE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EfCore.SqlRepository
{
public class BooksContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Book)
        .WithOne(a => a.Author)
        .HasForeignKey(aa => aa.BookId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Books");


    public void AddAuthor()
    {
        var author = new Author
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            name = "Jojn Doe"
        };

        Authors.Add(author);
        base.SaveChanges();
        
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Book> Book { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
        public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

[image: Working example]

Comment: I've tried everything relationship wise one-to-many but still doesn't work and get the error .Net EF doesn't allow you to add null references apparently I wonder if there is a workaround for this or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok I see problem now - in Books you reference itself public Book? Book { get; set; } but you should reference Author. I will my answer with complete working example.

Comment: That was actually a typo on Stack Overflow in my code is Author. I Changed my code to yours and still doesn't work. My problem is probably somewhere else. I Will keep trying with your logic, So thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I think this might be useful as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#:~:text=Nullable%20reference%20types%20are%20enabled,practices%20for%20working%20with%20them. 
Because you’re using new c# feature - nullable reference types. You should be careful when working with it and EF Core.

Comment: Yeah this will be quite useful, for now I'll look into documentations a bit more before trying anything else.

Comment: Found the problem, It was at Program.cs file now It's working alright. Thanks for verifying that the relationship was working and the problem wasn't there.